# Positioning of named nodes and paths within groupplot environments

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, intersections, groupplots

I am having issues with pgf, pgfplots and the groupplots library. The issue is best explained with an example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[group/group size=1 by 2]

\nextgroupplot
    \addplot {x} node[pos=0.5, name=first node]{};

    % I can do stuff with 'first node' here.
    \draw (first node) circle(5pt);

\nextgroupplot
    \addplot[name path=my plot] {x^2} node[pos=0.5, name=second node]{};

    % Of course, second node works here
    \draw (second node) circle(5pt);

    % This is not right
    \draw (first node) node {huh?} -- (second node);

\end{groupplot}

% This does work!
\draw[dotted, name path=vertical line] (first node) -- (second node);

% But this is not right
\path[name intersections={of={vertical line and my plot}}] (intersection-1) node {x};

\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Thus my questions(s):

- Why is the `first node` positioned incorrectly at first, but correctly outside the groupplots scope?
- What is going on with the intersection point? Again the document compiles, but the placement is anything but correct.
- Is there a preferred way of connecting plot points between successive `\nextgroupplot`? This is essentially what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Between `\nextgroupplot` your are effectively inside `\begin{axis}` environments. Generally you should only draw _stuff_ that belongs to two `axis` outside in a common scope. As you find in this case it needs to be outside the `groupplot` env, for exactly the same reasons.

Comment: @zeroth Any chance of an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This arises due to doing operations local within an axis environment which might change scales etc.

In general if you want to do intra-graphics you should do so outside the `axis` environments.
In this case it is important to recognize that the `groupplot` environment is a wrapper for several `axis` environments. Hence you should do your drawings *after* the `\end{groupplot}`. This you have already shown and figured out.

An intersection is another matter. The problem here is that each axis changes the coordinate system, individually, and the intersection library stores those paths in some form. Here it seems like the scales of the coordinate system is not updated. You may be required to do this in another way.